# Flutter I cant update my text when i check double variable with getx

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm using GetX for state management but i have a problem.

I have a messages page. Its showing messages and in that page when i hold a message it's opening edit mode for select some messages as usual. When i hold a message i changed my state like :

```
My edit mode variable =>  RxBool isEditMode = RxBool(false);
Opening edit mode =>  void openEditMode() => isEditMode.value = true;
```

also i have a text widget. When its not in edit mode it will write "Update" but when i open edit mode it will write "Select All" And if i select one of the message it will write "Remove Selected". Now in normally its writing select all and after i enter edit mode its writing select all. But when i add a message to my list its not changing to "Remove Selected".
This is how i made ;

---

On Controller ;

```
var selectedMessages = Rx<List<MessageModel>>([]); 
void selectMessage(MessageModel message) => selectedMessages.value.add(message);
```

On Text Widget ;

```
                  GetX<MessageController>(
                    init: MessageController(),
                    initState: (_) {},
                    builder: (controller) {
                      inspect(controller.selectedMessages.value);
                      return TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          controller.closeEditMode();
                          sharedController.showBottomNavBar();
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          controller.isEditMode.value
                              ? controller.selectedMessages.value.isEmpty
                                  ? "Select All" //I can see Select all
                                  : "Remove Selected" // But when selectedmessages.value doesnt empty i cant see that one.
                              : "Update" //I can see Update,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: ColorService.purple,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

What should i do ? Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After i add new item to my list. I learned i need refresh list like ;

from

`void selectMessage(MessageModel message) => selectedMessages.value.add(message);`

to

```
void selectMessage(MessageModel message) {
selectedMessages.value.add(message);
selectedMessages.refresh();
 }
```